# setting random seed standalone Rmath library

Tags: c++, linux, r

I try to generate random numbers in `C++` using the standalone `Rmath` library provided by `R`.

The best I have obtained has been:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* malloc, free, rand */
#define MATHLIB_STANDALONE
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
  int i;
  unsigned int SEED1, SEED2;
  double mu, sigma, PHI_X, *X;

  mu = 0;
  sigma = 1;
  SEED1 = time(NULL);
  SEED2 = time(NULL);
  set_seed(SEED1, SEED2);

  //int GetRNGstate();

  X = (double *) malloc(10);
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    X[i] = rnorm(mu, sigma);
    PHI_X = pnorm(X[i], mu, sigma, 1, 0);
    printf("X: %f, PHI(X): %f\n", X[i], PHI_X);
  }

  //int PutRNGstate();
}
```

If I understand it correctly, `GetRNGstate` should initialize the random seed instead of using `set_seed` but it doesn't work for me. I always generate the same chain of random numbers if use it. In addition, all the examples I have found in the web use `GetRNGstate()`, without having to declare it, but I cannot make it work this way and had to declare it as an `int`, am I doing anything wrong? In addition, should I wrap each call a random number generator with `GetRNGstate()` and `PutRNGState` or is it enought with setting them at the beggining/end of the code?

I'm aware that `Rcpp` makes this a lot easier when calling the code from within `R` but I just try to test the standalone version in `C++` directly.For information purposes I'm using Debian wheezy.

Comment: The two calls to `time(NULL)` are likely to be returning the same number (the resolution is only 1 second).

Comment: @  Loki Astari exactly, set_seed works but would have to wait 1 sec at least for generating a new random number. In any case it seems that `GetRNGstate()`has been coded for that purpose but cannot make it work.

Comment: `GetRNGstate()` and its `Put...` partner are to be used when you call C/C++ code from R.  That is not needed for standalone programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure (yet) what is wrong with your program, but here is a simpler and shorter one I wrote for myself a few years ago:

```
// -*- mode: C++; c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4; \
//         compile-command: "gcc -s -Wall -O3 -I/usr/share/R/include \
//         -o rmath_rnorm rmath_rnorm.c -lRmath -lm" -*-        

// Compare to
//    $ Rscript -e "RNGkind('Marsaglia'); \
//          .Random.seed[2:3] <- c(123L, 456L); rnorm(2)"        
//    [1] -0.2934974 -0.3343770

#include <stdio.h>

#define MATHLIB_STANDALONE 1
#include <Rmath.h>

int main(void) {

    set_seed(123, 456);
    printf("rnorm: %f %f\n", rnorm(0.0, 1.0));
    printf("rnorm: %f %f\n", rnorm(0.0, 1.0));

    return 0;
}
```

It still works as advertised:

```
/tmp$ gcc -s -Wall -O3 -I/usr/share/R/include -o rmath_rnorm \
                  rmath_rnorm.c -lRmath -lm
/tmp$ ./rmath_rnorm 
rnorm: -0.293497
rnorm: -0.334377
/tmp$ Rscript  -e 'RNGkind("Marsaglia"); .Random.seed[2:3] <- c(123L, 456L); rnorm(2)'
[1] -0.293497 -0.334377
tmp$
```

Same numbers as in R, predictably by setting the seed.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, the problem is just that I would expect the function to generate different random numbers without setting any seed, as with `R`. I was planning to do a simple simulation test, what would be the best way to set the seed for each draw if there is no alternative?

Comment: You could use my [random package for true random (hardware-based) draws](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=random). :)  More seriously, you may want to look into eg the OS sources for randomness, eg `/dev/random` -- see [this Wikipedia piece](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random).

Comment: sure it must be a very good one! :) thanks for the tip I will have a look.

Comment: You can use the random package for seeds -- but it needs a tcp/ip transaction to connect to [random.org](https://random.org) which does not work for all use cases. So `/dev/random`.